# What expression needed for universal naming of parts polygon feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, vbscript, string

For example, i have n count of polygons and little parts of it.

I want in field [Name] get string: "**PNum1(1)**".

where "1" - number of main polygon **[Num]**, "(1)" - number of part of main polygon **[Num_app]**.

In field calculator i use this expression: **"PNum" & [Num] & "(" & [Num_app] & ")"**.

[image]
[image]
On the screenshot is **Pnum 13(),Pnum 10()**
What i need write in expression if [Nomer_app] is Null and **"(", ")" must do not shown** (when main polygon don`t have any parts the string looks: **Pnum2()**)?

Comment: I think we may need you to include some screenshots.  By "n count of polygons and little parts of it" are you perhaps meaning a feature class with multipart polygons?

Comment: What does the attribute table corresponding to the polygons in your screenshot look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use this python expression to label your polygons. Empty strings, `None` (Null), `False`, 0 (+ others) all evaluate to `False` so you devise two separate strings.

Here's what it would look like in the label expression (don't need to use advanced):

```py
"PNUM {}({})".format([num], [num_app]) if [num_app] else "PNUM {}".format([num])
```

If you wanted to use `vbscript`, this should work. There's probably much prettier and simpler ways, though (need advanced checkbox):

```vb
Function FindLabel ([num], [num_app])
  If IsNull([num]) Then
    FindLabel = "PNum " & [num]
  Else
    FindLabel = "PNum " & [num] & "("&[num_app]&")"
  End If
End Function
```

I'm assuming your fields are already populated with polygon and part numbers.

For field Calculator:

```vb
"PNUM {}({})".format(!num!, !num_app!) if !num_app! else "PNUM {}".format(!num!)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very good.All things work.But only for  labeling.

Comment: Firstly i tray to use it in table to change field value by field calculator. Wrong. Its work only for Labeling. What expression  i need?

Comment: What expression to change field [Name] in table? With the same conditions like Labeling operation that you suggested earlier

Comment: @Jannik, label expression fields are enclosed with square braces. To use the same in Field Calculator, paste the python code (make sure the parser is python) and change the square braces to exclamation points.

Comment: Exactly, I forgot about it. Not so long ago, I began to understand it. you helped me very much. Thanx.
In addition to this theme. How is it possible to realize? if my basic polygons are numbered in order, when I added or changed the number of any polygons in order, the next number of order slips off. Only manually?

Comment: @Jannik, I'd recommend searching for ways to increment a field.